# Using the \int_step_function

Tags: latex3, xparse, l3draw

Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\miconcentric}{ O{0.08ex} }
 {
  \mathicon_concentric_circles:n { #1 }
 }
     
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathicon_concentric_circles:n
 {
 \draw_begin:
 \draw_linewidth:n { #1 }
 \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 }{ 1.00ex }
 \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 }{ 0.75ex }
 \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 }{ 0.50ex }
 \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
 \draw_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    Sample \miconcentric
\end{document}
```

In the `l3draw` manual, the following can be found:

> Within a drawing, the only commands that should appear are those
> directly aimed at drawing (from `l3draw`) and those which produce no
> typeset output. For example, it is possible to include loops inside a
> drawing using `\int_step_function:nnnN` or similar.

Is there a way to draw the concentric circles using `\int_step_function:nnnN`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `\int_step_function:nnnN` here, you would first need some way to convert the integer to a dimension for the radius.  Much easier here is to use `\dim_step_function:nnnN`, since you need a dimension.

To use `\dim_step_function:nnnN` you need to make `\draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 }{ <radius> }` into a single (one-token, or `N`-type) macro that takes the `<radius>` as argument, so

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathicon_circle_origin:n #1
  { \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } {#1} }
```

then use as

```latex
% \dim_step_function:nnnN { begin } {  step  } {  end  } \function
  \dim_step_function:nnnN { 0.5ex } { 0.25ex } { 1.0ex } \mathicon_circle_origin:n
```

Though if it's a one off, you can also use the `inline` version:

```latex
% \dim_step_inline:nnnn { begin } {  step  } {  end  } { inline function }
  \dim_step_inline:nnnn { 0.5ex } { 0.25ex } { 1.0ex } { \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } {#1} }
```

Here's the full code:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\miconcentric}{ O{0.08ex} }
  {
    \mathicon_concentric_circles:n {#1}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathicon_concentric_circles:n
  {
    \draw_begin:
    \draw_linewidth:n { #1 }
    % This
    \dim_step_inline:nnnn { 0.5ex } { 0.25ex } { 1.0ex }
      { \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } {##1} }
    % or this and the definition below
    % \dim_step_function:nnnN { 0.5ex } { 0.25ex } { 1.0ex }
    %   \mathicon_circle_origin:n
    %
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathicon_circle_origin:n #1
  { \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    Sample \miconcentric
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. For some reason or the other I forgot about the `##1`. I was attempting to create the function but had clashes with the optional argument in the command and conflicting the step function. :) I learnt something new.

Answer (score 7):

In this special case where the dimensions are integral multiples of a base one, namely `0.25ex`, with `\int_step_inline:nnn` it's easy:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\miconcentric}{ O{0.08ex} }
 {
  \mathicon_concentric_circles:n { #1 }
 }
     
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathicon_concentric_circles:n
 {
 \draw_begin:
 \draw_linewidth:n { #1 }
 \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { 4 }
  {
   \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 0.25ex * ##1 }
  }
 \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
 \draw_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Sample \miconcentric

\medskip

\LARGE
Sample \miconcentric[0.1pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]